# No route to host when trying to mount EFS on an EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nfs, amazon-efs

I am getting this output when running a mount -av on my EC2 instance:
I already have the allow incoming in the security group for the IP of EFS and the allow for the IP of the EC2 in the security group attached to the EFS. I don't and can't have DNS configured.

```
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Wed Sep 25 21:31:00 2019
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,vers=4.1,addr=mount.ip.address,clientaddr=client.ip.address'
    mount.nfs4: mount(2): No route to host
```

I have also tried this method with no luck:

```
mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport mount-target-IP:/   ~/efs-mount-point
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been testing with so many things that I copied the wrong IP to fstab. This works.